# Tweaking a client/js validation error only for a radio button container on a page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a page where there're several radio buttons. I want to tweak client validation **only for those radio buttons** on that page. Here's what it looks like when it's valid:

[image: when it's valid]

And here's when it's invalid -- doesn't look nice:

[image: when it's invalid]

I think it'll be better to apply validation to a whole container rather than to an individual radio button -- the validtion error will be placed under the two radio buttons.

How can I do that?

Otherwise, what's the best **and simple** way to make this validation error look nicer?

Note that I won't want to use an additional gem or js library for that.

Comment: An easy way to achieve this is to add the `required` attributes to those inputs and you'll get the browser's native validation error message. For a more elaborate usage you can use the browser's *validation constraint* API, https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and provide any code you have to make it easier for others to help you

Comment: @t3__rry that won't work